# Married Couples who doesn't have a child and they want to adopt a male or female baby

Tags: scripture, yajna

If the Married couples who doesn't have a child and they want to adopt a male or female baby and they need to do some yaaga in Hinduism for our ancestors blessings and the ancestors agreed that the child will be our Heir. Is it true?

> ஒரு மகனைத் தத்து எடுக்க விரும்புபவர்கள் அதற்க்கு முறைப்படியான ஹோமத்தீ வளர்த்து மந்திரங்கள் ஓதி அவனை மகனாக ஏற்றுக்கொள்ள வேண்டும். அப்படி செய்வதனால், தான், அவன் தத்து எடுதவருக்கோ அல்லது மூதாதையருக்கோ முறைப்படியாக தத்து எடுக்கபட்டவன் செய்கின்ற சிரார்த்தத்தால் மட்டுமே பித்ருக்கள் மகிழ்ச்சி அடைவார்கள் என்று சாத்திரத்தில் சொல்லப் படுகிறது.

Translation: Those who want to adopt a son must do a formal homage to recite the mantras and accept him as a son. By doing so, it is said that the Pithru is happy, only by the method that he is taken by the adoptive or ancestor of the ancestors

---

Please someone suggest and it would be appreciated.

Comment: If you ask a learned purohit who has done adyayanam in your area he will give the fitting answer. to your question. Because the couples do not have progeny they are adopting a baby from some one. The gothras will be different. In sankalpa both the gothras should be recited and the baby will come under the gothra  who will be father.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan: I will check