# What are the guidelines on child adoption?

Tags: dharma, culture, children

A neighborhood couple adopted a child a while back. The main criteria they saw, was if the skin colour & general appearance of that child is matching with them, so that it looks natural to others.

What are DhArmik criteria for any such adoption with respect to cast/class, age, region, religion, economy etc.?

<sub>Note: Certain tags are removed. See meta discussion: [Delete tags: "scripture" and "dharma-shastras"](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1189/delete-tags-scripture-and-dharma-shastras)</sub>

Comment: What is the need of tags scripture and Dharma shastras both? They are the same. Scripture is Shastra.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma then someone has to make it synonymous. To me "scriptures" is broader or superset to "Dharma-Shastra". All "Dharma-Shastra" are "Shastra" (scriptures). But vice versa is not true. In fact we should get rid of both of these tags before anyone srikes a gold badge.

Comment: There is a smriti tag which is applicable for Dharma shastras and Puranas but it is redundant to use in questions for Puranas because there is a separate tag for that. So, there is an ambiguity in usage of Shastra, Dharma Shastra, Smriti tags. Yes, someone should start a discussion.  Yes, we should get rid of ambiguous tags before some one strikes gold. That is why I asked a question on scripture tag.  TBH, I feel there is no need of two tags on scriptures in this question.

Comment: Related [Married Couples who doesn't have a child and they want to adopt a male or female baby](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14819/married-couples-who-doesnt-have-a-child-and-they-want-to-adopt-a-male-or-female)

Comment: Are u looking for guidelines that are culture based or that are scripture based? Also what is the relevance of the tag Dharma here which may or may not be culture dependent?.. So IMO it's wrong choice of tags @iammilind

Comment: @Rickross Just read the question. The criteria is in the question and not the tags."What are **DhArmik criteria** for any such adoption" . To me it is clear. Tags don't say what OP is looking for. The body or title does.

Comment: @Rickross, "adoption of a child" is a cultural event. Different societies have different norms & preferences. In regards of Hindus, I am seeking to know how does Dharma-s stance on this aspect. For example, if I am a poor man then it's not DhArmik for me to adopt a rich orphan. Another example is that, I have seen that within brothers, a childless couple adopts another brother's child which is not the eldest. This appears DhArmik to me. There might be several norms like this. All tags are apt, as they cover my question.

Comment: If you are looking for Dharma's stance then the Dharma Shastra is the right tag here.. culture etc are less important..so again it's wrong choice of tags all over. if culture is more important then means you are looking for answers what different cultures say on  it..yes the tags u added can be added but not before adding the most relevant ones which u have missed adding..@iammilind

Comment: "What is the dharmik guideline for child adoption" is quite vague.. and you will get off topic close votes.. and this is what i was talking about..dharma shastra is the ideal tag for this Q which if added gives the impression that you already know where to find the answers from.. that shows the OP has got preliminary knowledge of his topic's relevance to Hinduism..right now it does not look like a proper Hinduism Q even without the right tags..@iammilind

Comment: Knowing the guidelines on adoption is not off-topic. Obviously it is from Hinduism pov because it is asked here and absence of a certain tag doesn't make a question off-topic.